# md-autocomplete not rendering on HTML page

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using this code to search for states as the user types state name in autocomplete box. I am getting the results on console but that is not showing item text HTML

```
<md-content class="md-padding">                         
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">                               
      <md-autocomplete                                   
          md-no-cache="true"
          md-selected-item="$ctrl.displayStates[$index].state"                                    
          md-search-text="$ctrl.searchText"
          md-items="item in $ctrl.querySearch($ctrl.searchText)"
          md-item-text="item.display"
          md-min-length="0"
          placeholder="Select Role?">{{item.display}}
        <md-item-template>
          <span md-highlight-text="$ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
          No role matching "{{$ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
          <a ng-click="$ctrl.manageRoles('ADD')">Create a new one!</a>
        </md-not-found>
      </md-autocomplete>
    </form> 
    </md-content>
```

JS

Sorry previously I have posted some wrong JS code

```
$ctrl.querySearch=function(query) {     
      var results = query ? $ctrl.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : $ctrl.states,deferred;      
          console.log("With my Testings --->",results);
        return results;
    }

function loadAll() {
  var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
          Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
          Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
          Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
          North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
          South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
          Wisconsin, Wyoming';

  return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
    return {
      value: state.toLowerCase(),
      display: state
    };
  });
}

function createFilterFor(query) {
  var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

  return function filterFn(state) {
    return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
  };

}
```

Comment: please post `states` and function `createFilterFor `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to `value`

```
<md-content class="md-padding">                         
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">                               
      <md-autocomplete                                   
          md-no-cache="true"
          md-selected-item="displayStates[$index].state"                                    
          md-search-text="searchText"
          md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
          md-item-text="item.value"
          md-min-length="0"
          placeholder="Select Role?">{{item.value}}
        <md-item-template>
          <span md-highlight-text="searchText" 
                md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.value}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
          No role matching "{{searchText}}" were found.
          <a ng-click="manageRoles('ADD')">Create a new one!</a>
        </md-not-found>
      </md-autocomplete>
    </form> 
    </md-content>
```

<kbd>[Demo Codepen](https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/LjgWwq?editors=1010)</kbd>

---

I omitted `$ctrl` for test purposes only

Comment: @ Maxim Shoustin Sorry Previously I have Posted some wrong JS code now I have posted correct one So I cant go with item.value

Comment: @ Maxim Shoustin code seems to be ok but I am using Angular Library 1.5.8 and material library 1.1.4 and code pen you have shown is using material library 1.0.0  and angular 1.4.8 is that causing the problem

Comment: @VishalArthamwar lol. still works: https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/PKymZN?editors=1010

Comment: @VishalArthamwar maybe some style issue with close button

Comment: @ Maxim Shoustin my code is under ng-repeat display data in table format under tr and td tags is that the Issue

Comment: @VishalArthamwar mate, I posted answer based on your question and your code snippet. I don't see `ng-repeat`, .....and td tags . Please remove your question and post new one or change it.

Comment: @ Maxim Shoustin Thanks for Help because of your codepen I was able to think in another way else till the point I was thinking it is the problem with versions, I found the Issue, This issue is due to I put the md-autocomplete on the top of bootstrap's modal-content.So my list is getting populated behind modal.Now I am trying to find the solution,Please help me if you know the solution for this